# How to fix random "The wait operation timed out" with EF 6 and SQL Server AWS RDS

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

### PROBLEM:

Since a DB migration, I have many intermittent exception from SQL timeout. All what I now after my 2 months of investigation:

- All my .NET C# apps using EF 6 are impacted
- Whatever time in the day (day or night) BUT the more traffic we have, the more timeouts happens
- No matter what method used (.ToList, .Single, .First, .SaveChanges) which trigger a call to the DB
- Whatever DB table impacted (small or big)
- Whatever query complexity is (large query with 20 join or juste un smal query whith a select ... where Id = 1)
- Whatever calling mode (write/read)
- Whatever calling dbContext directly or by a property navigation (with lazy loading activiated)

### ENVIRONMENT:

**> INFRASTRUCTURE:**

- 1 AWS RDS (db.m4.2xlarge), 32 GB of RAM, 8 vCPU, 100 GB SSD with SQL SERVER 11.0.xxx in Read Committed Snapshot Isolation level
- UC around 5%, Connection DB around 45, very few E/S write or read, 20GB of RAM available (on 32GB), 90GB free space (on 100GB SSD)
- Optimisation of index (rebuild, drop/create), query plan, stats
- Increase parallelism
- NO blocking, NO deadlock, NO suspended session (sp_who2), NO CXPACKET problem, very large free memory or disk space
- BD usage: around 25 request by second, nothing exceptionel...

**> APPLICATIONS :**

- 20 C# applications (Batch, UI ASP MVC, ...) with EF 6 mainly (lazy loading ativated) or EF Core with CommandTimeout to 45s (instead of default 30s)
- LINQ to Entities optimization (Inlcude, replaced by raw sql on very complex query, remove WHERE 1=0 queries, ...)
- DbContext management optimized (open/close juste when needed, no leak connection)
- Many memory caches added to avoid DB call
- All application pools are recycled every day

### EXCEPTION:

When a .ToList, .First, .Single or any method which trigger a call to the DB from EF throw a message like these:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.
```

or

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Session Provider, error: 19 - Physical connection is not usable)
```

### RESULT:

When I run SQL Profiler on my PROD database (impossible to reproduce the problem on others dev environment), I have a query who run juste 1 sec (not 45 sec...) and my code return only after 45s the timeout... Like the problem was on network/transport layer... But how to monitor this ? How to be sure that the problem was not on C# or DB server but between the 2 ? Have you some advice to make these timeouts disapear before I kill myself ?

### EDIT 22/04/2019:

I confirm that when EF 6 execute the query (trigger by a .ToList for example), the query on my database took only 78 microseconds (yes, microseconds...) to execute and... EF are waiting for 45 seconds to give me an error like "A transport-level error has occurred..." : WHY ? Why EF 6 don't get the result from the database ? Why the answer is lost in the wild ? Like a connection lost by randomly...

### EDIT 25/04/2019:

Finally we decide to develop a DbExecutionStrategy with a retry system. I'm very sad to end like this but we runnig out of time and that solved our problems.

Comment: Possibly related to this [https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7800](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7800)

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm using DbExecutionStrategy as well, but it is not viable for update operations...